# How exactly does a JSON.stringify automatically map to my DTO

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, webmethod

I have an object in jquery:

```
function SaveRequest() {
var request = BuildSaveRequest();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({'model':request}),
    url: "somepage.aspx/JsonSave",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    },
    error: function (res, status, exception) {
    }
});
return false;
}

function BuildSaveRequest() {

var request = {
    customerName: $("#CustomerName").val(),
    contactName: $("#ContactName").val(),
};

return request;
}
```

And I have the following c# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string JsonSave(MyModel model)
    {
    }
}

public class MyModel 
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}
```

When the ajax call goes, the web method JsonSave automatically place the values (CustomerName, & ContactName) from the jquery object 'request' into the appropriate properties in object 'model'.  How does it know to do that???

Comment: Model binder is a beautiful thing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: Wow! That is very interesting, thx for sharing @dbarnes.  So this works exactly the same even though I'm sending data from a web form and not a MVC application?

Comment: I created an answer just to help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added answer from comments:

[Model Binders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) are a beautiful thing.

I would recommend reading the source found [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs) this is for MVC but I'm pretty sure it acts the same in webforms as well.

It is really smart and checks the in request for the data so it doesn't really matter if you use webforms or mvc. You can even create our [own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).